# (JAVA/KOTLIN) Can I "convert" a string to call an existing variable? like "varname".getvariable?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Can I use a string to call an existing variable or object by name?
The question is kind of abstract but I'm looking for something like this.

Example

````
var number = 5

var getnumber = "number"

if (getnumber.(???) > 10)
{...}

or 

if ("number".(???) > 10)

{...}```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible: At the class level, local variable names do not exist at all.

The usual solution is to stop thinking 'python' or 'javascript', where each object is a kind of `HashMap<String, Object>`, and think java.

If you just can't get your head out of python/javascript space, or the problem fundamentally boils down to this idea, well, you have your answer:

Make a `Map<String, Object>` instead of a local variable:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("number", 5);
var getNumber = "number";
if (map.get(getNumber) > 10) { .... }
```

Comment: To extend on this: via Reflection you can access Object/class member variables, e.g. the 'fields' of a class: `final Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("fielName"); int val = field.getInt(obj)`

Comment: @JayC667 Not sure how that is relevant. Local variables have nothing whatsoever to do with fields.

Comment: As you've stated correctly, accessing method variables is not possible with pure Java. But what is possible is do to that on class and member variables. So perhaps this helps him, and he restructures his code in a way that makes it possible to use member variables. Who knows... Just wanted to give him a full picture. Or you go ahead and extend Lombok a bit more, do some preprocess/compilation and bytecode weaving magic, and he can have what he needs with your lib ;-)

Comment: You want to advise someone new to java to __use reflection__ to write code in a pythonesque fashion in java? That's.. terrible advice.

Comment: That's not a want, and that's not an advice. It's a solution. One of many possible solutions. Let him decide whether he wants to use that or not. He himself knows that it's "kind of an abstract question". But do we know his ultimate intentions? When it comes to programming basics, I would never hold back on solutions, because someone *might* not have the skillset/level that I personally deem necessary. We can assume the XY problem here, but that goes multiple ways. So we can bother or we can attribute to a more complete picture.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a fixed amount of entries, you might use an enum:

```
private enum class Size(val cm: Int) {
    SMALL(50),
    MEDIUM(100),
    LARGE(150),
}
```

Usage could be like:

```
val sizeOne = Size.MEDIUM
val sizeTwo = Size.LARGE

if(sizeOne.cm > sizeTwo.cm ) { ... }

val sizeHundred = Size.values().find { it.cm == 100 }
```